# %Total from SQL Table

Tags: sql, oracle

Using below code;

```
SELECT CASE GROUPING_ID(period) WHEN 1 THEN 'TOTAL' ELSE TO_CHAR(period) END AS period,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Completed'   THEN 1 END) AS completed,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'WIP'         THEN 1 END) AS wip,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Not Started' THEN 1 END) AS not_started,
       COUNT(*) AS Total
  FROM transition_tasks_new
 GROUP BY ROLLUP(period)
 ORDER BY period;
```

I'm getting data in the attached format:

[image: Screenshot attached]

which is fine. However, I need to get the %complete for each of them.
For ex - % Pre-Update "Complete" would be 2/28 i.e 7%;

I wrote this query;

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN period = '1-Pre Update' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS value,
       COUNT(taskid) AS max_value
  FROM transition_tasks_new
 WHERE status='Completed'
```

but it's not working as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT X.*,
    ROUND(X.COMPLETED / X.TOTAL * 100,
        2) AS PERCENT_COMPLETE
FROM
    (WITH SAMPLE_DATA AS
            (SELECT '1-Pre-Update' AS PERIOD,
                    3  AS WIP,
                    2  AS COMPLETED,
                    23 AS NOT_STARTED) SELECT PERIOD,
            SUM(WIP) AS WIP,
            SUM(COMPLETED) AS COMPLETED,
            SUM(NOT_STARTED) AS NOT_STARTED,
            SUM(WIP + COMPLETED + NOT_STARTED) AS TOTAL
        FROM SAMPLE_DATA
        GROUP BY PERIOD) X
```

Comment: Should I replace SAMPLE_DATA with my database table? I'm not clear what "3 AS WIP", "2 AS COMPLETED", "23 AS NOT_STARTED" is trying to do. Can you please explain. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Divide the value by the total and multiply by 100 to calculate the percentage:

```sql
SELECT CASE GROUPING_ID(period) WHEN 1 THEN 'TOTAL' ELSE TO_CHAR(period) END
         AS period,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Completed'   THEN 1 END) AS completed,
       ROUND(COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Completed'   THEN 1 END)/COUNT(*) * 100, 3)
         AS percent_completed,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'WIP'         THEN 1 END) AS wip,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Not Started' THEN 1 END) AS not_started,
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   tasks
GROUP BY ROLLUP(period)
ORDER BY period;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tasks (period, status) AS
SELECT 1, 'Completed'   FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'WIP'         FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Not Started' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Other'       FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Completed'   FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'WIP'         FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Completed'   FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Not Started' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2;
```

Outputs:

> | PERIOD | COMPLETED | PERCENT_COMPLETED | WIP | NOT_STARTED | TOTAL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 3 | 42.857 | 2 | 1 | 7 |
> | 2 | 2 | 66.667 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
> | 3 | 4 | 66.667 | 0 | 2 | 6 |
> | TOTAL | 9 | 56.25 | 3 | 3 | 16 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=44ad47ff3da82b42594f3f7d0da10cae)*